# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException and the parameterized constructor

Tags: java

I have a class Foo as follows:

```
public class Foo extends Bar
{
    public Foo(com.example.X displayState, com.example.Y parent)
    {
        super(displayState, parent);
    }
}
```

The Bar class is shown below:

```
public abstract class Bar {

    public Bar(com.example.X displayState, com.example.Y parent)
    {
        // do something with received params
    }
}
```

Additionally, there is a factory class with the following method:

```
 public static Object getInstance(Class theSourceClass, Class theTargetClass, Class[] parameterClasses, Object[] parameterValues)
 {
     Class theClass = (theTargetClass == null) ? theSourceClass : theTargetClass;

     try
     {
         Constructor classConstructor = theClass.getConstructor(parameterClasses);
         return classConstructor.newInstance(parameterValues);
     }
     catch (NoSuchMethodException exp)
     {
         // log
     }
```

The problem is that the `NoSuchMethodException` exception always arises:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.Foo.<init>(com.example.X, com.example.Y)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2715) 
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1659)
at com.example.MyFactory.getInstance(MyFactory.java:30)
```

I have debugged the code and the class information has correct details about the defined constructor; however, the exception is here.

Does anybody have any idea what is missed? Thanks!

Comment: How do you invoke the `getInstance()` method when you get this exception?

Comment: Do you have a constructor in Bar that accepts displaystate and parent?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Presumably yes, otherwise an unresolved compilation error would occur rather than a runtime exception?

Comment: Yep, I do. Just edited the initial message, please take a look at the Bar class definition

Answer (score 2):

The following example will produce an instance of `Foo`.  The example ensures that a constructor in `Bar` exists that accepts `X` and `Y`.

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo extends Bar {
    public Foo(com.example.X displayState, com.example.Y parent) {
        super(displayState, parent);
    }
}
```

**Bar.java**

```
import com.example.X;
import com.example.Y;


public class Bar {

    public Bar(X displayState, Y parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

**X.java**

```
package com.example;

public class X {

}
```

**Y.java**

```
 package com.example;

public class Y {

}
```

**Test.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

import com.example.X;
import com.example.Y;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class[] classes = {X.class, Y.class};
        Object[] values = {new X(), new Y()};

        Object obj = getInstance(Foo.class, null, classes, values);

        System.out.println(obj);
    }

    public static Object getInstance(Class theSourceClass,
            Class theTargetClass, Class[] parameterClasses,
            Object[] parameterValues) {
        Class theClass = (theTargetClass == null) ? theSourceClass
                : theTargetClass;

        try {
            Constructor classConstructor = theClass
                    .getConstructor(parameterClasses);
            return classConstructor.newInstance(parameterValues);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, it does and I have a similar sample project in eclipse as well; however, in the real project for some reasons the described issue exists... But anyway, thanks!

Comment: @CyrilDeba Glad I could help, hopefully you will find the issue in your project.  At least you have a working example.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem was the different version of the compiled Bar, X, Y, and factory classes which were used for the compilation and in runtime. Let me explain.

All 4 guys (Bar, X, Y, and factory class) are compiled and come from the library file for the Foo class compilation. However, the production system always re-compile these classes.

I created the library, connected it to the build path, and forgot about it. Technically, the project has no errors during the compilation yet the reflection fails.

The solution was simple - remove the library and use re-generated Bar, X, Y, and factory classes for the Foo compilation.